# Using a BoxView to "cut" through another BoxView and revealing it's background

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.forms

I have a StackLayout, containing a BoxView:

```cs
layout.Children.Add(new BoxView()
{
    HorizontalOptions = LayoutOptions.FillAndExpand,
    VerticalOptions = LayoutOptions.FillAndExpand,
    Color = Color.Black,
    Opacity = 0.6
});
```

This adds a black layer over the whole StackLayout, which "darkens" everything.

I want to add another BoxView on top of this, that "cuts" through the existing dark layer, so that the background behind the black BoxView is visible.

How can this be achieved?

I already tried using a grid and basically drawing BoxViews around the center, leaving a spot in the middle blank, but that's not really what I'm after.

Here's a visual representation of what I'm trying to achieve:
[image: emulator]

As you can see, the entire page is darkened (the black BoxView). The white square in the middle would be the other BoxView that cuts throught the black BoxView. Thus revealing the "non-darkened" background.

Comment: Can you visually show us what you want it will make all our lives easier! Also showing us what you have already achieved would be a bonus!

Comment: I think you would need to use 4 different box views to form the top/bottom/left/right of your "dark" view, leaving a "donut hole" in the middle

Comment: @Jason I tried this already and it works, but it leaves for very little flexibility. For example, what if I want the square in the middle to be a circle?

Comment: if you need that kind of flexibility I'd try creating a mask with SkiaSharp or looking at options for a custom renderer.

Comment: Or make a custom renderer for your initial boxview such that the native view draws itself, and it could draw whatever you want, i.e. draw a black box with a hole, either rectangular or circular, in the middle. You could use SkiaSharp, but the native iOS and Android APIs have sufficient drawing capabilities to fairly easily achieve a box with a hole in the middle.

Comment: Do you also want to move that center box ? if not I think it can be possible with grid with same row and column